# Basis of differential one-form confusion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand one-forms in the context of general relativity. Lee (Introduction to Smooth Manifolds) says that at a point $p$
  and with a vector field $X$
  we define a covector field $df$,
  called the differential of $f$, by$$df_{p}\left(X_{p}\right)=X_{p}f.$$

My question is, is that definition true for any basis or only for a coordinate basis?

I understand that if $\omega^{a}$
  is the one-form basis and $e_{b}$
  is the vector basis then, again by definition, $$\omega^{a}e_{b}=\delta_{b}^{a}.$$
 I also understand that using coordinate bases $\omega^{a}=\mathrm{d}x^{a}$
  and $e_{b}=\partial_{b}$
  then (from the first definition) $$\mathrm{d}x^{a}(\partial_{b})=\partial x^{a}/\partial x^{b}=\delta_{b}^{a}.$$
Thanks.

Comment: The first expression you give is coordinate-independent, hence holds for any choice of basis.

Comment: Note the *absence* of any indices in your first equation: It is independent of coordinates! **EDIT**: Phoenix beat me to it...

Comment: I didn't know that (obviously, otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question - seems a tad harsh to downvote after six minutes). How would I write the first equation, with indices, to show it referred, for example, only to coordinate bases?

Comment: choose a basis $\{e_k\}$ for the tangent space at $p$, then $X_p = a^k e_k$ and therefore $\text df(X)|_p = a^ke_k(f)$.

Comment: This, as it is, has nothing to do with general relativity. It's just a very basic question in differential geometry.

Comment: Profuse apologies. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Phoenix87 - thanks very much. That's much clearer.