# Total confusion about differential one-forms and non-coordinate bases

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I asked this question recently ([Basis of differential one-form confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570204/basis-of-differential-one-form-confusion)), thought I understood the answer, but now realise I don't. Lee (*Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*) says that at a point $p$
  and with a vector field $X$
  we define a covector field $df$,
  called the differential of $f$, by$$df_{p}\left(X_{p}\right)=X_{p}f.$$

My original question was, is that definition true for any basis or only for a coordinate basis? I was told that because of the absence of any indices in this definition it was coordinate-independent. OK, I then asked for an example with indices using a non-coordinate basis. @Phoenix87 then responded with:

“choose a basis $\{e_{k}\}$ for the tangent space at $p$, then $X_{p}=a^{k}e_{k}$ and therefore $df(X)|_{p}=a^{k}e_{k}(f)$.”

I thought I understood that, but now I'm confused as to why there's a basis vector on the rhs. As I understand things (tenuous at best, I admit), a one-form acts on a vector at a point to spit out a number. This happens because if $\omega^{a}$ is the one-form basis and $e_{k}$ is the vector basis then, again by definition, $$\omega^{a}e_{k}=\delta_{k}^{a}.$$

So why is there an orphan $e_{k}$ on the rhs of @Phoenix87's answer? Also, what is the non-coordinate one-form basis of $df$ on the lhs?

I know this is really basic stuff, but I just don't get it. I'm a self-studier, by the way.

Comment: There is no phantom $e_k$ on the right-side of the equation you speak of: you must read $e_k(f)$ as ONE expression, which is the tangent vector $e_k$ evaluated at $f$. Recall that a tangent vector in the end is a map from functions to numbers, so $e_k(f)$ is a number.

Comment: So is there a relationship between a coordinate vector basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}$ and a non-coordinate vector basis $e_{k}$?

Comment: Afraid I'm still confused as to how there are *any* basis vectors on the rhs. Given the definition $\omega^{a}e_{k}=\delta_{k}^{a}$ I would have thought both the basis one-forms and basis vectors on the lhs would have all disappeared in a puff of 1's and 0's.

Comment: in terms of directional derivative $e_k(f)={\rm grad}f\cdot e_k=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}$

Comment: @janmarqz - But doesn't $e_{k}(f)={\rm grad}f\cdot e_{k}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{k}}$
  imply $e_{k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{k}}$,
  which is a coordinate vector basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $e_k$ is not an orphan and the fact that you think it is, makes me suspect that you miss the summation convention. Under that convention, when an expression contains an index both as an upper index and as a lower index, the expression is interpreted as a sum over that index. Restating more explicitly:

Choose a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ for the tangent space at $p,$ then for every vector $X_p$ in that space there exist unique coefficients $a^1,\ldots,a^n$  such that

$$X_p=\sum_{k=1}^na^ke_k$$

Covectors are elements of the dual vector space, i.e, linear maps from the original vector space to the real numbers. The covector $df$ at the point $p$ is given by its effect on a general vector $X_p$

$$df(X_p)=\sum_{k=1}^na^k(e_k(f)).$$

Comment: Thanks for that. I was aware of the summation convention. I've come thus far via self-studying general relativity, where the usual bases are the coordinate basis vectors $e_{\mu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ and basis one-forms $\omega^{\nu}=dx^{\nu}$. That's why I was confused by janmarqz's answer, which seemed to me to imply $e_{k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{k}}$, which is a coordinate basis? Also, as I asked in my previous comment, does $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{a}}dx^{a}$ for both coordinate and non-coordinate bases? If yes, what are the basis one-forms for $df$?

Comment: $e_k=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ *is* a basis. As a basis of one-forms you can interpret $dx^a$ as $d$ applied to the coordinate function $x^a$.

Comment: But my question was asking for examples of non-coordinate bases.

Comment: That is rather difficult because it can be proven that for every basis of $T_pM$ one can actually construct a local coordinate system around $p$ for which the given vectors are precisely the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}.$ The next best thing is to "innocently" work in one coordinate system and use functions that accidentally define a different system, like the functions $x,y,z$ in a spherical coordinate system in $\mathbb R^3.$